# Open Youtube App and go back to my App

Tags: ios, youtube

For my project, I would like to watch some Youtube video. However, when I embed Youtube's Player in a `UIWebView`, the quality is really low. So, I decide to play the videos on the Youtube App if she's on the phone.

My problem is that my user can't go back to my app once the video is finish.

I know there's a URL Scheme for Google Maps App that add a button to go back to your app, but I didn't find anythings for the Youtube App.

Any idea ?

Comment: Check out this: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper#controlling_playback, you can use a Youtube iOS SDK to embed videos in your app.

Comment: I didn't want to add an other library, but well, it's working :) thanks !

Comment: Try this 
NSString *stringURL = @"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WZH30T99MaM";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:stringURL];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];

Comment: @Kalpesh yes, this will open Safari or Youtube App if she is installed. But I don't have any way to go back to my App.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't any public URL Scheme for the YouTube iOS App like Google Maps has for callbacks.

You can use this SDK for embedding Youtube videos into your app: https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/ios_youtube_helper

Check out the Youtube Developer Site: https://www.youtube.com/yt/dev/hu/api-resources.html, if they will enable an URL Scheme with callbacks, it will be available here.